# Using Python to grab output from a C++ program (thru cout)

Tags: c++, python

I have the following code in Python

```
import subprocess
import time

info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

t1 = time.clock()
h = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\test.exe"], startupinfo=info) 
h.communicate()
t2 = time.clock()-t1

print "Return Code:", h.returncode
print "Duration:", t2
```

This works great if I am looking for the program's return code but what if I want to grab things that the program simply cout's to the screen and manipulate them as variables in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [return values from `.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

Comment: Do I need to access it through the communicate() that's already there? what do I output at the end? When I output h.stdout, it returns None

Comment: If you're using `communicate()` you might as well access it that way. The other option is to pass `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to the `Popen` constructor, which will result in `h.stdout` being populated. But that's kind of overkill when you're already using `communicate()`.